# 24bpp to 8bpp conversion C with raw image data

Tags: c, image, bit-manipulation, transformation, color-palette

I am currently trying to convert raw binary image data (512 x 512 24bpp) to a 512 x 512 8bpp image by using 3bits for the R channel, 3 for the G channel, and 2 for the B channel. However when using my code my picture comes out grey scale? Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
/*24 bit per pixel - 8 bit per pixel transformation*/

unsigned char buf[512][512][3];
unsigned char in[512][512][3];
unsigned char out[512][512][3];
unsigned char pix[512][512];

int main(){

    FILE *fp, *output;
    int i, j;

    /*open file*/
    if((fp = fopen("LennaRGB512.data", "rb")) == NULL){
        printf("error opening file\n");
    }

    /*read file into buffer*/
    for (i = 0; i < 512; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 512; j++) {
            buf[i][j][0] = fgetc(fp); /*r*/
            buf[i][j][1] = fgetc(fp); /*g*/
            buf[i][j][2] = fgetc(fp); /*b*/

            in[i][j][0] = buf[i][j][0];
            in[i][j][1] = buf[i][j][1];
            in[i][j][2] = buf[i][j][2];
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    output = fopen("lenna_8bpp.data", "wb");
    for(i = 0; i < 512; i++){
        char pix[512][512];
        for(j = 0; j < 512; j++){
            out[i][j][0] = (in[i][j][0] * 8) / 256;
            out[i][j][1] = (in[i][j][1] * 8) / 256;
            out[i][j][2] = (in[i][j][2] * 4) / 256;
            pix[i][j] = (out[i][j][0] << 5) | (out[i][j][1] << 2) | out[i][j][2];
            fputc(pix[i][j], output);
        }
    }



    fclose(output);
    return 0;
}
```

There are tons of questions on doing this with .bmp files and others but I can't find any help with manipulating the raw image data pixel by pixel.

Comment: I think your problem is that the file is still being read as 24-bit colour, however you have compressed each pixel to just 8-bits, so each pixel has three pixels' data in it for each channel. Thus grayscale. Check the format of your .data files.

Comment: Take the image IO routines from here https://github.com/MalcolmMcLean/babyxrc . You need to set up a palette with the colours mapped to your 8-bit key, then save as BMP or GIF.

Comment: What is the _mode_ of GIMP viewing?  [Sample](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tutorial-quickie-change-mode.html).

Comment: It should be viewed as RGB because I simply want to reduce the colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the commenters.  I think the grayscale is very likely an artifact of your viewer rather than your conversion.  However, your conversion can also be improved.  Try the following output loop:

```
unsigned char pix;   /* don't need 512*512 of them. */
unsigned char r, g, b;
for(row = 0; row < 512; row++){
    for(col = 0; col < 512; col++){
        r = in[row][col][0] >> 5;   /* keep 3 bits */
        g = in[row][col][1] >> 5;
        b = in[row][col][2] >> 6;   /* keep 2 bits */
        pix = (r << 5) | (g << 2) | b;
        fputc(pix, output);
    }
}
```

You are only processing one pixel at a time, so you only need one `pix` value.

For each of the `r`, `g`, and `b`, color components (remember to specify `unsigned char` throughout), use `>>` (right shift) to drop all the bits except the most significant.  This is simpler and more clear than the `*8/256` sequence.  Also, I believe `*8/256` only works because arithmetic is promoted to `int` — if it were done in `char`s, the `*8` could cause overflow and lose data.

**Edit** The problem is indeed in the display.  I have posted a palette and instructions on [my blog](https://devwrench.wordpress.com/2016/10/18/an-r3g3b2-palette-for-gimp-and-how-to-use-it/) since the full contents are too long for the space here.  Yes, I know link-only answers are bad :( .  I just saved it into the Archive in case of link rot.

You do need to open the image as Indexed, and then assign the colormap of the image.

Comment: I just gave it a try and for some reason it is now spitting out 3 grayscale images smaller than the first side by side. I'm guessing each seperate image is the corresponding R, G, and B. The image comes out to being 512 * 170 (split into the three photos)

Comment: @s.gang Very strange!  Did you change your input format or viewer settings?  I re-read the code in your question and can't find anything in this answer that should rearrange data.

Comment: Nope! All I'm using to open the files is gimp and since its raw data I must input width height and image type. In RGB mode it does the 512 * 170 triple picture, however if I change the loading mode to Indexed, a full 512 x 512 grayscale picture will show up (which is clearly color reduced because file size is about 1/3 that of the original) Looks like my problem is in the combination of the bits after transformation

Comment: @s.gang Updated blog post with a better palette.

Comment: thanks so much for your help, this really helped me get my head wrapped around it haha.

Comment: @s.gang Glad to hear it! :)